# Are there non-linear functions that satisfy $f(1)=3$ and $f(1+x)=f(1)+f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I solved this question:
$$f(1)=3\\f(1+x)=f(1)+f(x)\\f(50)=?$$ my try is in below
$$f(2)=f(1)+f(1)=3+3=2\times 3\\f(3)=f(1)+f(2)=3+6=3\times 3\\ 
\vdots\\f(50)=3\times50$$ and $f(x)=3x$ work in here. Actually, this was a multiple choice and it passed. But my question is about the different types (non-linear functions) that fit in this relation. Can anyone help me?

To say as clear as possible:

> Is there another type of function that covers those conditions?

Comment: There are non-linear functions which satisfy $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb R$. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation).

Comment: @Umesh Shankar: Why you delete your answer?

Comment: Your method clearly would work for all positive integers and could be tuned into a proof by induction which is easily extended to $0$ and negative integers. Non-linear solutions would only give different values for non-integers.

Comment: f(x) = 3x is the only possible solution, you can prove this by induction as well

Comment: @Yves Daoust , you mean integers?

Comment: @AadiSinha: you are right, integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the condition $f(1+x)=f(1)+f(x)$, specifying the value of $f(1)$ will specify the function value of every integer.

The best we can do is if we specify $f(x)$ for each $x\in (0,1)$, we will be able to retrieve the value of $f(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb R$.

A function that satisfies the given is $f(x)=
 3\lfloor x \rfloor \text { if } x \in \mathbb R $ but it is not exactly continuous or linear.

Comment: Do You mean something like  floor function ?

Comment: Yes, I shall edit it to reflect that